# Good general LaTeX style practice

Tags: best-practices, resume

I just created my first document in LaTeX (a resume) and while I'm familiar with good practices in programming, I'm not familiar with what constitutes good practices in a markup language like LaTeX. Below is the code for my resume (content edited for privacy).

I'd like to know which style/formatting practices I used are good, and which are bad. For example, I'm guessing that using `$\bullet$ .... \\` instead of an `itemize` is not good practice, but I wasn't sure how to embed an `itemize` within `cvlist` without creating an extra space between the list and the content above the list.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
% margins
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
% arranging headers spacing
\newcommand\textbox[1]{\parbox{.333\textwidth}{#1}}
\usepackage[NoDate, LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% remove page number
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{cv}{}
% distance between labels and body
\setlength{\cvlabelwidth}{22mm}

% heading
\noindent\textbox{Term Address:\hfill}\textbox{\hfil \LARGE \textbf{Name}\hfil}\textbox{\hfill Home Address:}\\
\noindent\textbox{Street \hfill}\textbox{\hfil email@email.com \hfil}   \textbox{\hfill Street}\\
\noindent\textbox{City \hfill}\textbox{\hfil (555)-555-5555 \hfil}\textbox{\hfill Address}

% horizontal line
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.3mm}

% Education
\begin{cvlist}{}
\item[\textbf{Education}]
\textbf{School} \hfill Cambridge, MA\\
\textit{Candidate for Bachelor of Science in Everything} \hfill June 2099 (expected)\\
Relevant Coursework: Cooking (Fall `13), Puppetry \hfill GPA: 5.0/5.0\\
for Fun (Fall `13), Probability and Stuff (Fall `13),\\
Differential Differentiation
\end{cvlist}

% Experience
\begin{cvlist}{}
\item[\textbf{Experience}]
\textbf{Company} \hfill City\\
\textit{Position} \hfill June - August 2015\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task

\textbf{Company} \hfill City\\
\textit{Position} \hfill January - May 1908\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task
\end{cvlist}

%Leadership
\begin{cvlist}{}
\item[\textbf{Leadership}]
\textbf{Organization} \hfill City\\
\textit{Position} \hfill August 2000 - present\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task

\textbf{Program} \hfill City \\
\textit{Position} \hfill August 2055 - present\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task

\textbf{Organization} \hfill City\\
\textit{Position} \hfill December 1856 - June 2010\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task\\
$\bullet$ Task
\end{cvlist}

%Skills
\begin{cvlist}{}
\item[\textbf{Skills}]
 Everything, \LaTeX
\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: General piece of advice: if you are doing something simple more than once or twice (e.g., `\noindent\textbox{<words>\hfill}`), you could/should create a more abstract command (e.g. `\tbcmd`) that incorporates everything that is repeated over and over.  Generally speaking, the more flexibility that needs to be built into these higher abstraction command means that your willingness to spend time creating them should increase as your facility with *TeX increases: that is, if it takes you 4 hours to do something you could easily do in an ad hoc manner, it might be better to go ad hoc (this time).

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any popular coding style for (La)TeX as GNU Coding Style for C and PEP8 for Python. But IMHO, following some of PEP8 rules as indentation, use of spaces (not tab), maximum line length (this will help when debuging) and split your document/project across various files are good things. And as jon say, use `\newcommand` to not repeat your self.

Comment: Wouldn't that question be more appropriate on Code Review Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More detailed explanation, please read the `enumitem` manual by invoking `texdoc enumitem` from your terminal.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
My compact items:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt,noitemsep]
  \item haha
  \item hihi
  \item hoho
\end{itemize}

My more compact items:
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep]
  \item haha
  \item hihi
  \item hoho
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the second itemize, there's no need to use `noitemsep`; `nolistsep` is enough (it kills itemsep also).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for commenting. Update has been made.